# What is the best method to keep all logs in one place and be able to access them

Tags: php, logging, background, laravel-4

I have a web application using multiple background workers. All those workers are on different servers. Now my problem is. I want to be able to have a log, per user, and be able to output it to them using Ajax. Now, my question is, how can I store all logs in one place (could be externally using some service) and be able to access them. Note that I need them per user.

If there are any questions, ask them.

EDIT: I thought of MySQL but I think the load would be too much for it.

Comment: I've found [paper trail](https://papertrailapp.com) to be excellent for this kind of task.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/getsentry/sentry its also free.

Comment: I am using Sentry for my error logging, but the basic idea now is I just want to get messages to my users from the background script.

Comment: Any ideas on that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think MySQL can't handle it, but it most likely can.

As long as you use efficient queries and indexes then will have no problems. Since the log is per user it is best to create it yourself as you will have total control.

If you are worried, you only have to have a running log total for each user and either backup the rest / move them to a different table / discard them.